# Access a script's variables and functions in interpreter after runtime

Tags: python, console, interpreter

So let's say I have a script `script1`. Is there a way to interact with `script1`'s variables and functions like an interpreter after or during its runtime?

I'm using IDLE and Python 2.7, but I'm wondering if I could do this in any interpreter not just IDLE's.

Say in my script, `get = requests.get("example.com")`. I'd like to hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or whatever to run my script, and then instead of the console unloading all of the variables from memory, I'd like to be able to access the same `get` variable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a serious question. You might need to consult this page:

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options

Note the `-i` option, it makes interpreter enter interactive mode after executing given script.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
#file : foo.py
import requests

def req():
    get = requests.get("example.com")
    return get
```

and then run the script from a console

```
import foo
get = foo.req()
```